# How to process a click without letting it go out of bounds

Tags: java

```
public void processLightClick(int row, int col) { 
    states[row][col] = !states[row][col];
    states[row+1][col] = !states[row+1][col];
    states[row-1][col] = !states[row-1][col];
    states[row][col+1] = !states[row][col+1];
    states[row][col-1] = !states[row][col-1];

    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++){
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++){
            if(states[row+i][col+j] == true){
                lights[row+i][col+j].setFill(ON_PAINT);}
            else if(states[row+i][col+j] == false){
                lights[row+i][col+j].setFill(OFF_PAINT);}
        }
    }

    turns++; 
    System.out.println(row+":"+col);
    status.setText("Turn Number " + turns);
}
```

I have this code that when you click a square it changes the state of itself and the 4 squares touching it (north, south, east, and west). My problem is when I click on one of the border squares it obviously gives me an out of bounds error.

*EDIT*
Tried fixing it and am still getting an error with this code.

```
public void processLightClick(int row, int col) {

    //loop for the inner square 
    for (row = 1; row < GAME_SIZE - 1; row++){ 
        states[row][col] = !states[row][col];
        states[row+1][col] = !states[row+1][col];
        states[row-1][col] = !states[row-1][col];
        states[row][col+1] = !states[row][col+1];
        states[row][col-1] = !states[row][col-1];
    }

    //loop for the outer sections
    for(row = 0; row < GAME_SIZE; row++){
        states[row][col] = !states[row][col];
        states[row-1][col] = !states[row-1][col];
        if(states[row][col] = states[0][0]){
            states[row][col+1] = !states[row][col+1];
        }
        if(states[row][col] = states[0][4]){
            states[row][col-1] = !states[row][col-1];
        }
    }

    changeLight(); 
    turns++; 
    System.out.println(row+":"+col);
    status.setText("Turn Number " + turns);
}
enter code here
```

Comment: No, don't do as @DavidZhou recommends since this error should not be a caught exception. Rather what you need to do is to check for boundary conditions before accessing your array elements, and *not* try to obtain an array element from an out of bounds element. This is nothing more than basic arithmetic and elbow grease. Really you should be able to figure this out on a sheet of paper.Truly.

Comment: Catching the exception is considered poor practice. Instead, checking to see if the clicked square is a border square and then taking the appropriate action is more elegant than just catching and squishing the exception. What if you had something else wrong with your code that caused the same exception that you didn't expect to happen, and, since the exception is squished, didn't receive any feedback about?  (@HovercraftFullOfEels: took the words right out of my mouth a few seconds before I could click "comment" :D)

Comment: sorry guys, the exception part was not what I really meant. I deleted the comment and instead, made a (hopefully) useful solution for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the click was made on one of the border cells, and then call the appropiate methods to change their state and color, something like

```
if(row == 0) // it is the first row
    // call the method for changing the cell underneath
else if(row == n-1) // assuming n is the number of cells
    // call the method for changing the cell above
else 
    // call both methods
```

and the same goes for columns, and finally you change the clicked cell.

You could achieve this by creating just one method that receives parameters `i` and `j` for changing `cell (i,j)`, and you just use the correct ones in each case.

Also, I'm assuming `states` is a boolean 2d array, so there is no need to check `== true`, and you could use `!states[i][j]` in the other case (which is unnecesary, if it is not true, it gotta be false)

EDIT:

something like this

```
public void processLightClick(int row, int col) {
{
    if(row == 0) // it is the first row, change the one below only
        changeLight(row+1,col);
    else if(row == n-1)
        changeLight(row-1,col); //change the one above only
    else
    {    //change both
        changeLight(row+1,col);
        changeLight(row-1,col);
    }

    if(col == 0) 
        changeLight(row,col+1);
    else if(col == n-1) 
        changeLight(row,col-1);
    else
    {
        changeLight(row,col+1);
        changeLight(row,col-1);
    }

    changeLight(row,col); // the clicked cell  
}
```

And your `changeLight(row,col)` should change state and color for the specified cell

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're saying. I moved the for loop out and into a new method and made it much simpler coding but my problem is in top 5 lines inside processLightClick. I tried making a for loop that started at 1(instead of 0) and ran until <4 instead of <=4 to box in the smaller square where all those statements would be true and made another loop that checked the spot and did changed the neccessary surrounding squares but still get an error message. I'll upload what I changed

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, you don't need a loop through all your cells, you can check them individually (it's just 4 you have to check)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid it, check

```
row+i < max
col+j < max
row-i >= 0
row-j >=0
```

don't use for loop, write the 4 cases 1 by 1. check the above constraint